# UILocalNotifications not firing when scheduled

Tags: ios, swift

Well, none of the existing discussions presented a working solution for me. So here's my code to show local notifications. What am I missing?

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.alertBody = "Reminder" // text that will be displayed in the notification
notification.alertAction = "open"
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName


notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
print("Notification scheduled")

notification.userInfo = ["title": "Test", "UUID": "1"]
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfMonth

UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

I'm aware that when the app is in foreground there should be an event in didReceiveLocalNotification. I do not get an event in the appdelegate's didReceiveLocalNotification or the notification. However, when I use presentLocalNotificationNow with the notification - I the  didReceiveLocalNotification in app delegate does get called. I also tried with other fireDates but it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Oh and I do have the below code in my appdelegate didfinishlaunchingapplication

let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()

```
let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Comment: Local notifications in iOS 10 require user authorization. Do you have code obtaining authorization? — Also you should now be using UNNotificationRequest, not UILocalNotification.

Comment: Yes I ask for authorization, and it's there in my post.

Comment: Regarding UNNotificationRequest I cannot use it since I'm supporting iOS 9 as well

Comment: @RahulAhuja why you use  `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()`you need remote notifications also?

Comment: @RahulAhuja are you using swift 2.3?

Comment: You have to use `UNNotification` to work in iOS 10 i suppose, just put it in `#available(iOS 10.0, *)` to register again for iOS 10

Comment: "Yes I ask for authorization, and it's there in my post." No it isn't. And if you want this to work on iOS 9 and 10 you will need two entirely separate sets of code. UILocalNotification won't work if you link against iOS 10.

Comment: @matt it is :) registerUserNotificationSettings asks for authorization. Also, I got this code working on iOS 9 and 10 both. Suprisingly I just had to comment out the line that sets userInfo

Answer (score 2):

I had been testing, and this are my results, the problem seems to be related with time unit `weekOfMonth` with `day` works as intended, here is the picture of console log, using XCode 8.2, device iOS 10.2, still working

[image]

```
func scheduleTestNotification()
{
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = "Reminder" // text that will be displayed in the notification
    notification.alertAction = "open"
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

    notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.default
    notification.fireDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
    print("Notification scheduled")

    notification.userInfo = ["title": "Test", "UUID": "1"]
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.day
    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    debugPrint(UIApplication.shared.scheduledLocalNotifications!)
}
```

but if I use `weekOfMonth` then

[image]

I think you can use this code as a workaround, it's not the best solution, but maybe can help you to achieve what you need

```
func scheduleTestNotification()
    {
        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertBody = "Reminder" // text that will be displayed in the notification
        notification.alertAction = "open"
        notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

        notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.default
        notification.fireDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
        print("Notification scheduled")

        notification.userInfo = ["title": "Test", "UUID": "1"]

        UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
        notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.day
        notification.fireDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: notification.fireDate!)
        UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
        debugPrint(UIApplication.shared.scheduledLocalNotifications!)
    }
```

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

To send notification in iOS 10 you need to ask permission as bellow before you fire the notification.

```
  func requestPermition() {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
            if settings.authorizationStatus != .authorized {

                let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .sound];
                center.requestAuthorization(options: options) {
                    (granted, error) in
                    if !granted {
                        print("Something went wrong")
                    }else {
                        print("permition granted")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`UILocalNotification` is deprecated in iOS 10 you may use `UNUserNotificationCenter` instead.to fire a notification try bellow code

```
   //to fire notification after 5 seconds.
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5,
                                                    repeats: false)

    //Set contents to be desplayed on the notification
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Reminder"
    content.body = "Test reminder"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.categoryIdentifier = "myCategory"


    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "textNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    //set UNNotificationActionOptions .foreground if you need to open when button tapped.
    let action = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "remindOpen", title: "Open", options: [.foreground])
    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "myCategory", actions: [action], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("notification error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested and this code works on my side, iOS 10 with XCode 8.2

```
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert ], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = "Reminder" // text that will be displayed in the notification
    notification.alertAction = "open"
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName


    notification.fireDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
    print("Notification scheduled")

    notification.userInfo = ["title": "Test", "UUID": "1"]
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.minute

    UIApplication.shared.cancelAllLocalNotifications()
    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

The method didReceiveNotification is called whenever the app pushes a local notification. My repeatInterval is minute instead of weekOfMonth. I think weekOfMonth is the problem because when I change repeatInterval to weekOfMonth, I did not receive notifications, the method didReceiveNotification never called.

Answer (score 0):

So I also encountered a same problem.
I was trying to fire UILocalNotification from background fetch.  I had UILocalNotification scheduled, I stepped through in Xcode, make sure that scheduleLocalNotification was called, but it only fired about 1/5 times.

It seems that scheduling UINotification from background fetch simply does not work reliably in iOS 10.  I switched to using UNUserNotification and it fires reliably, every time I step through the code.